# Microservices Api gateway and Identity Server 4 kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, consul, envoyproxy, ocelot

I have microsevices and SPA app. All of them run on docker with docker compose. I have ocelot api gateway. But gateway knows  ip address or container names of microservices for reaching .  I add a aggregater service inside ocelot app. And I can reach to all services from aggregator service with ips.

But I want to move kubernates. I can scale services. there is no static ip. How can I configure .

I have identity service. This service knows clients ip addresses. Again same problem.

I searched for hours. I found some keywords. Envoy, Ingress, Consul, Ocelot . Can someone explain these things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your question is related to [Service Discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#motivation).

In Kubernetes, the native way an "API Gateway" is implemented, is by using [Ingress resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). If you use a cloud provider, they usually have a product for this, or you can use a custom deployed within the cluster.

*Service Discovery* the Kubernetes way, is by referring to [Service resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), e.g. the Ingress resources maps URLs (in your public API) to services. And your app is deployed as a [Deployment resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), and all replicas (instances) is exposed via a Service resource. An app can also send request to other apps, and it should address that request to the Service resource for the other app. The Service resource does load balancing to the replicas of the receiving app.

Comment: I made some research.I found istio. What is differences between envoy,ingress, istio , Consul? Can you explain shortly please ? Im sorry. Maybe one of them an apple and another is pear I dont know.

Comment: yes. Envoy is a proxy. Istio is a Service Mesh product that uses Envoy as a proxy. Consul can aslo be used as a Service Mesh product. Ingress is a kubernetes resource and an Ingress Controller is needed if you use Ingress resources. You may use an "ingress gateway" from a Service Mesh. I don't think your app need to use Ingress resources if you use a Service Mesh. It is easier to start with Ingress, and then move to Service Mesh after that - it is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the service name to connect with the service instead of the client IP.

```
for example : curl HTTP://<service.name>.<namespace name>.svc.cluster.local
```

now if you are looking forward to list of API gateway and Identity server for Kubernetes

there are several options however it all depends on requirement.

For basic requirement nginx ingress and other ingress is available while if you are looking for API gateway :

- Kong APi gateway
- Ambassador api gateway
- TYK API gateway

part of that service mesh can be also useful not in all scenario because it's mostly used for managing internal traffic (east-west).

API gateway is mostly used for managing edge traffic.

List of identity servers :

- keycloak
- Cognito IAM (AWS)

ingress controllers :

- GCE ingress
- Nginx ingress controller
- Kong ingress controller
- Gloo
- HA proxy
- AKS gateway
- istio ingress